# With dill.dumps(), getting error as "can't pickle tensorflow.python._tf_stack.StackSummary objects"

Tags: dill

I have tensorflow model object and trying to serialize through dill.dumps
but getting following error:
can't pickle tensorflow.python._tf_stack.StackSummary objects

Comment: This is probably a better question to ask on `dill` github.  You'll want to give your version of python, dill, and tensorflow -- and you'll want to post the traceback you receive.  There are a few `dill.settings` that modify how things are serialized, and sometimes an alternate setting can work.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Will take this question over dill github with more inputs.